# Generate URL constants in openapi generator

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I've read some excerpts from the documentation of the openapi generator but haven't been able to find something about URL constants. Can it generate String constants for each endpoint?

For example I have country.yml with the contents below:

```
openapi: 3.0.3

info:
  title: service, country
  description: service REST interface
  version: '1.0.0'

tags:
  - name: country
    description: Country operations

paths:
  /country:
    get:
      description: Get countries
      tags:
        - country
      operationId: getCountries
...
```

As can be seen it contains the endpoint "/country"

Would it be possible to configure the generator so that it creates the corresponding String constant in the API interface?

For example:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "...")
@Tag(name = "country", description = "Country operations")
public interface CountryApi {

String COUNTRY = "/country"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to configure the generator so as to create the corresponding String constant in the API interface.

For this, you will have to make use of the templates which is structured as mustache file. Basically the openapi-generator has a deafult set of templates attached with it, for each of the generator type. You will have to restructure the respective mustache file as per your requirement and enable the generator to utilize the same while generating the server or client code.

Please find below the snapshot of a template file defined in the openapi-generator. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/api.mustache
[image]